# Spotipy current_user_saved_tracks not returning anything

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to get my spotify data using Spotipy but when i run:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope="user-library-read user-top-read", client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri='http://localhost/')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

and then

```
tracks = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
```

it returns empty json data.
The only time it work is when I do
`top.current_user_top_artists(limit=10, time_range='long_term')`
but not with a different parameter value for time range.